# How can I append an array keys and values to an html element?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array output like the following:

```
Array
(
    [DPPSI_1_50_min] => 11
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_2_40_min] => 10
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_3_30_min] => 9
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_4_20_min] => 8
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_5_10_min] => 6.1
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_6_0_min] => 3.77
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_1_50_min] => 14
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_2_40_min] => 15
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_3_30_min] => 16
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_4_20_min] => 17
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_5_10_min] => 18
)
1
Array
(
    [DPPSI_6_0_min] => 19
)
1
```

What I need to do is append these to an html data-* attribute. So something like this:

```
<select data-DDPSI_6_0_min="19">
```

What's the best way to do this? I've seen the implode functions as well as the http_build_query method. The http_build_query gets me super close, however I'm left with a bunch of encoded chars that look like this:

```
0%5BDPPSI_1_50_min%5D=11 1%5BDPPSI_2_40_min%5D=10 2%5BDPPSI_3_30_min%5D=9 
3%5BDPPSI_4_20_min%5D=8 4%5BDPPSI_5_10_min%5D=6.1 
5%5BDPPSI_6_0_min%5D=3.770%5BDPPSI_1_50_min%5D=14 1%5BDPPSI_2_40_min%5D=15 
2%5BDPPSI_3_30_min%5D=16 3%5BDPPSI_4_20_min%5D=17 4%5BDPPSI_5_10_min%5D=18 
5%5BDPPSI_6_0_min%5D=19
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to _loop through_ the array and _create_ the desired `select` element based on the array index and value?

Comment: A `foreach` loop, it lets you write the keys easily. Note that PHP has many built-in functions related to array keys. Avoid `http_build_query()`, this is not made for that

Comment: No. I have the select drop down already generated. I'm trying to get these values into data attributes like the <select> above. I need to validate them using JS and each all of these values need to be appended to the <select> dropdown with the key values `<select data-key="value">`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: "I have the select drop down already generated"  How are they being generated? They're obviously not being generated the way that you want them.  This task should be done during the generation of these elements.

Comment: So I'm inside a WordPress loop. And my select looks like this: '<option 
        value="'.$product['term_id'].'" 
        data-details="'.$product['description'].'"
        data-name="' .$product['model']. '"
        data-serial="'.$product['serial'].'"'.
        foreach ( $tolerances_arr[0] as $key => $value ) {
            echo "data-{$key}=\"{$value}\"";
        }'">
        '.$product['description'].'
      </option>';'

Comment: That is the creation of your `option` elements, not your `select` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming your data array looks like this:

```
$array = array(
  array(
    'DPPSI_1_50_min' => 11,
    'DPPSI_2_40_min' => 10,
    ...
  )
);
```

you could create an html tag for each array value:

```
foreach ($array as $eachArray) {
  foreach ($eachArray as $key => $value) { ?>
    <div data-<?= $key ?>=<?= $value ?> ></div>
  <?php }
}
```

**EDITED according to your comment:**

You can´t concat a foreach cons. You´d have to save the first part of the tag in a var and then concat each array value like this:

```
$tag ='<option value="'.$product['term_id'].'" data-details="'.$product['description'].'" data-name="' .$product['model']. '" data-serial="'.$product['serial'].'"';


foreach ( $tolerances_arr[0] as $key => $value ) { 
  $tag .= " data-{$key}=\"{$value}\" ";
}

$tag .='"> '. $product['description'].' </option>';
```

This is in case you want to create all your custom tag attributes in only one option tag

Comment: This is very close. But I'm getting an error saying I an unexpected foreach now: ' <option 
        value="'.$product['term_id'].'" 
        data-details="'.$product['description'].'"
        data-name="' .$product['model']. '"
        data-serial="'.$product['serial'].'"'.
        foreach ( $tolerances_arr[0] as $key => $value ) {
            echo "data-{$key}=\"{$value}\"";
        }'">
        '.$product['description'].'
      </option>';

Comment: You can´t concat a foreach cons.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're best off with a simple foreach loop.

```
foreach ( $myArray as $key => $value ) {
    echo "{$key}=\"{$value}\"";
}
```